# Can Texticle do geolocation search too?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, geocoding

I don't fully understand if [Texticle search](http://tenderlove.github.com/texticle/) for PostgreSQL can be used with geolocation searching. I ask this because I need both Full-text searching and the ability to sort by distance and find near a location for my Heroku application. I am using [Geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) to do the latter and I wanted to know if I can just add it inside Texticle and it would work with it?

Comment: Texticle is not Textile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it will be an issue. Texticle provides access to methods which leverage fulltext search functionality that is already a part of PostgreSQL. Geocoder just needs access to a database for persistence.